# laravel simple form not working

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

OK, it has taken me forever (since Friday) to configure everything related to Laravel, mcrypt & PHPStorm and now I am only trying to display a simple form field - it's completely blank

```
    @section('content')

    {{ Form::open() }}
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}

    @stop
```

When I inspect element, no form exists and there are no errors - WTF?

My file is called index.blade.php

Within my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

The documentation makes it look so easy

Comment: are you extending a layout ?

Answer (score 0):

As lagbox says you probably just need to extend a layout.  So you have master.blade.php (in a layouts folder in your view probably) which has your HTML head/body tags etc:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/dist/css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        @yield('content')
        <script src="/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you have your index.blade.php file which will have something like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

{{ Form::open() }}
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
    {{ Form::text('username') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

Take a look at the Laravel Blade documentation for more info: [Laravel Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates)